# How can I get an element from within a frameset frame using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frames, frameset

I need to access and element from within a frameset frame. For example if I have the following markup:

```
<frameset rows="33%,33%,*">
  <frame src="frame1.html"/>
  <frame src="frame2.html"/>
  <frame src="frame3.html"/>
</frameset>
```

How can I get some element from one of the child frames? I have tried this:

```
window.frames[1].getElementById('someElementId')
```

This results in a type error :

> getElementById() is not a function.

Can someone assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to get the Document object for the frame.

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementById('someElementId')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<frameset rows="33%,33%,*">
<frame id="demo" src="frame1.html"/>
<frame src="frame2.html"/>
<frame src="frame3.html"/>
</frameset>
```

Answer:

```
document.getElementById("demo").contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo")` returns null !!

Comment: @Heitor, my quick guess is that you didn't nest things in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {/*code here*/});`, which might be useful. That said, I get that `document.getElementById("demo").contentDocument` is null even with the wrapper, though `document.getElementById("demo")` does return `<frame id="demo" src="frame1.html">` using Canary. Weirdness is afoot.

Answer (score 8):

You can try using framename as well

```
window.frames['frame_name'].document.getElementsByName('element_name');
```

Comment: this does not return windows object hence will not work while window.frames[1] return windows object hence works.

Comment: getting frame by name here which is a string i.e frame_name , gave me an error , `element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'` , had to set `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` to true in tsconfig.json