# How to add an eventlistener in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I don't know how to create an asp in fiddle but I created the JS.Please check the [link](http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14bj) .Imagine I have a button`(button id: button2)` on `(src : 'ccc.de';)`, and when i click that button(in `ccc.de`) I should catch the event in js

My actual src page is not `ccc.de`, my src page contains an asp with a button`(button id: button2)` on it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a onclick event to an element using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018170/how-to-add-a-onclick-event-to-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no relation to angular or JSON for that matter.

If you want to attach an event listener to your button, you can try preventing the default action of the button by doing something like this.

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 function_to_call();
});
```

Comment: hey sorry for the title I forgot to change the title and thanks for the reply.

but I am sorry to say, the solution you gave is not working

Comment: Can you make a fiddle maybe? I don't see why it should not work. Did you change #btn to whatever the id of the button is?

Comment: hey I dont know how to create an asp in fiddle but i created the JS
please check the link :  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14bj

imagine i have a button(button ID: button2) on src : 'https://ccc.de', and when i click that button I should catch the event in js

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

         $(document).on('click', "#button2", function() {
             alert("button2 clicked");
         });
 });
```

//instead of `document` in click event, you should use parent of `$button2`

Or you can use

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

         $( "#button2").on('click', function() {
             alert("button2 clicked");
         });
 });
```

Comment: working on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/30w751ew/3/ but not working for me in local

Answer (score 0):

Your code are ASP code, or ASP.NET WebForms, maybe ASP.NET MVC?

At fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14bj) I see iFrame. Remember, if your button in iFrame, and your code with setting event handler in owner document, you should search button for setting your event inside of iFrame. It's will be not fount in parent document. Maybe problem is here. If you have PostBack (or another things, that reloads page), and button2 inside iFrame, then botton2 event handler will be lose after iFrame reloading. So, you will need set listener for event again, because it will be new button2 after reload (inside iFrame).

If you use ExtJS, then better set event on ExtJS button by component config. Somethin like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
text: 'Button2',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
handler: function() {
    alert('You clicked the button 2!');
}});
```

Here example with two ways: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14hs

For better understood of your problem, culd you provide full code of this pages (if you couldn't use fiddle for asp, use  http://pastebin.com/ or another service of posting sources).

I hope I wrote something helpfull (but not shure). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply my case a bit different please the whole code
my extjs code to create window is http://pastebin.com/Y0X6fqSW (see from line 90)
my ASP code that's called in the window is http://pastebin.com/QGKTSC2x (see at line 430 for button)

Comment: At first look, I see you want close ExtJS window by clicking on button in iFrame: <button class=stdbutton onclick="window.close();" id=button1 name=button1><%=lng_close%> </button>

Right?

Comment: What there happens: 
1) I added onload handler to iFrame autoEl (look at html)
2) In handler I found the ExtJS window, that contains this iFrame and has found the button in iFrame document. Remember that in iFrame another document, you should search the button exactly in this document.
3) I added handler with js closure, that close the window.

This can help you better understand this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509934/how-can-i-get-an-element-from-within-a-frameset-frame-using-javascript

Comment: And one more.. Never, NEVER don't call variables in your code 'window' or 'document'. Never don't use names, that alrady used by DOM, language, etc. In your fiddle example you named local variable as 'window'. It's make many problems with debuggong and understandig of code logic in some places.

Comment: Hey bro all at once that worked like a charm millions of million likes